# How to keep track of history of transactions and rollback when needed?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Let's say I'm maintaining an Activity log of a user in `UserActivity` model.

```
class UserActivity(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    query = models.TextField()
```

1. How to implement and what fields are required on this model, so that I would be able to
   rollback a transaction in history at any time?
2. What are its cons and dependencies?

I know `transaction.atomic`. Think of this as doing a transaction a few days ago and rolling back today.

Comment: It might be better to simply use something like `django-simple-history` (https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.2/). This will keep track of the changes of a model, and will, normally be able to restore the model to a given timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a tool like [**`django-simple-history`** [PiPy]](https://pypi.org/project/django-simple-history/). You need to add some middleware, and define a [**`HistoricalRecords()`**](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.2/quick_start.html#track-history) on the models you want to keep track on.

It will create an extra table per model you keep track of that will store the changes (additions, updates, removals) together with the user that made the update, the timestamp, and an optional reason.

You can for example query the state of an object in history, like:

```
from datetime import datetime

my_model_object.history.as_of(datetime(2019, 7, 2, 7, 56))
```

to retrieve the `my_model_object` in the state it was on 2-7-2019 7:56:00.